# .net Desktop application deployment with database in entity framework

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, deployment

I have created a simple.Net, C# Windows Application of payroll system using Entity framework code first approach.
It uses default built-in (local DB) from .Net itself.

I can create setup, and it is working fine with my system, which is used to developed the said application (that means that system contains .net development components components).

And trying to install on other system,obviously not working.

For deployment phase, I need to install this setup on multiple systems.
database should be common, which need to depoy on other system, that is connected using a LAN.

As I’m new to this, could someone provide me some guidance would be appreciable.

Comment: Please rewrite the question. It is hard to read and even harder to understand. For me it is not clear, what you mean.

Comment: ok. Edited.. please ask me some specific question for more clarity. I may bad in English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is related to the connection to the database. Entity Framework checks for an existing database that you defined in the context class that inherits from DbContext. If it does not exist Entity Framework will create it locally for you in development. But when your ready to deploy your application you need to define the connection string to the database. Since your are using Entity Framework Code First I would also recommend using the Entity Framework Power tools that you can download from NuGet. You can read more on the DbContext, and setting up the models here.
[Entity Framework Code First Context](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592674.aspx)

I would inspect this aspect of the article:

```
public class BloggingContext : DbContext 
{ 
    public BloggingContext() 
        : base("BloggingCompactDatabase") 
    { 
    } 
}
```

The base defines the connection string in your App or Web config file. Telling the system what database it is connecting to, and how to make that connection. I hope this helps!